# Android Random string generated from int

Tags: android, string, random, int

Basically Im trying to generate a random string when the page loads up. The problem is I dont know how to make the created random integer as a variable for my switch case. Can anyone modify my code and help me?

CODE

```
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ask_2 extends Activity {

TextView ActivityNumber;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ask2);

    ChooseActivity();
}

private void ChooseActivity() {
    Random myRandom = new Random();
    TextView textGenerateNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.generatenumber);
    textGenerateNumber.setText(String.valueOf(myRandom.nextInt(2)));
    TextView textGenerateDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.generatedesc);
    switch (myRandom) {
    case 0:
        textGenerateDesc.setText("Hello0");
        break;
    case 1:
        textGenerateDesc.setText("Hello1");
        break;
    case 2:
        textGenerateDesc.setText("Hello2");
        break;
    }

}
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Activity " />
<TextView android:id="@+id/generatenumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Number" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/generatedesc" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Description" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You could generate random numbers between the ASCII values of 'A' and 'Z' and create a string from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't switch on random, you should first get an int:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int myRandom = rand.nextInt() % 3;
```

or, as you implemented it

```
Random myRandom = new Random();
//...
switch(myRandom.nextInt() %3) {
```

Comment: perhaps it would be better not to switch at all, and use an array instead.

Comment: Thank you MByD. It works. Do I just change the number 3 to 10, if I have 10 switch cases?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have `myRandom.nextInt(2))`. This will generate 0 or 1, but in your switch you check for values of 0, 1 or 2. I assume you want one of these values.

```
Random myRandom = new Random();
int randomNumber = myRandom.nextInt(3);
TextView textGenerateNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.generatenumber);
textGenerateNumber.setText(String.valueOf(randomNumber));
```

Comment: this generates a number only...?

Comment: If you want it more explicit: `String str = String.valueOf(randomNumber)`.